# Qt name collision, but no_keywords not an option

Tags: c++, qt, macros, compiler-errors, signals-slots

I have a dilemma. In a program I'm writing using Qt, I use a (non-Qt) library that uses a Qt keyword in its headers as a name (the library being pf_ring to be precise, and the name "slots") and so I get compilation errors. But if I turn off Qt keywords using the no_keywords option, the compiler complains about another library's headers (this one Qt-based) which use Qt keywords like "signals" and "slots."

So how can I fix this? I can think of only two options neither of which is very satisfactory:

1. I can change the second library's header files so that they comply with the no_keywords mode (changing "slots" to "Q_SLOTS" and so forth).
2. I can move the pf_ring related code into its own sub-project in which I can turn off Qt keywords or simply not use Qt at all.

Can you suggest another, hopefully more elegant and less troublesome, solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on the library, if it's a small one you can make a "wrapper" header (only or not) that doesn't expose *slots* or expose it in a wrapper_namespace (note that you can use `#undef slots` ).

Comment: #undef-ing slots was what I did in the end; something like:
    #undef slots
    #include <pfring.h>
    #define slots Q_SLOTS